# Formik field from nested component not updating

Tags: javascript, formik

I have the following scenario:

- main component with a few fields that Formik handles. Everything fine here.
- sub component that renders inside the main form and uses Formik's Field component, same as the fields in the main component do. These fields are not getting updated.

Main component:

```
...
return (
 <Formik
   enableReinitialize
   initialValues={{
     name: this.state.name,
     newName: this.state.newName, // this field is inside the nested component
   }}
   validationSchema={mySchema}
   onSubmit={...}
 >
   {
     ({ errors, values, ... }) => (
       <Form ref={this.formRef}>
         ...
         <Field name="name" type="text" />
         ...
         <NewNameForm />
       </Form>
     )
   }
 </Formik>
);
```

NewNameForm component:

```
...
return (
  <div>
    <Field name="newName" type="text" />
  </div>
);
```

Is my approach wrong, can I just nest components with extra fields like this? `newName` isnt' getting updated so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by passing Formik's `setFieldValue` method to subcomponent's props like this:

```
onNameChange={(name) => {
  setFieldValue('newName', name);
}}
```